Blazor server login
I'm working on a blazor server software, and I've now finished the database part of the server. Now there are functions such as creating a new user, deleting a user, modifying a user, verifying a user, and so on. They work fine. However, I now want to make the client log in (you don't need to provide pages, you just need to provide logic) and add restrictions to some pages (you can log in to view, you don't need to provide specific pages either), what should I do?
Users should not need to log in every time they visit, and the login information should be saved. I don't want to use user authentication provided by Microsoft because it's too complicated, and I don't need the system to be very secure, just block non-logged-in guest access. If there is a location that is not clearly described, please feel free to ask.

Maybe I can save the user data with cookie, but I don't know how to do that. There is a function I have wrote that can return a bool value when you give it user name and password.

Depending on your needs, you could use Browser storage. If you use .net8, I suggest you disable prerender(SSR) because SSR cannot access Browser storage.
Cookie is Ok, but it will be harder because you have to implement the js interop to operate the cookie. I would recommand using Browser LocalStorage to save the login User information. Here is a small sample you could reference:

Create .Net8 "Blazor Web App" template. (rendermode" server, gloal")
Modify the App.razor like below to disable prerender

...
    <HeadOutlet @rendermode="new InteractiveServerRenderMode(false)" />
...
    <Routes @rendermode="new InteractiveServerRenderMode(false)" />
...


Install package Blazored.LocalStorage
Add/Modify following codes:
UserInfo.cs

    public class UserInfo
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        //save the expireation time for check
        public DateTime ExpirationTime { get; set; }
    }

MyAuthProvider.cs (This is where the blazor get user identity for "authorizeview" to check)
using Blazored.LocalStorage;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization;
using System.Security.Claims;
...
    public class MyAuthProvider : AuthenticationStateProvider
    {
        private readonly ILocalStorageService _localstorage;

        public MyAuthProvider(ILocalStorageService localstorage)
        {
            this._localstorage = localstorage;
        }
        public override async Task<AuthenticationState> GetAuthenticationStateAsync()
        {
            var userInfo=await _localstorage.GetItemAsync<UserInfo>("userinfo");
            if ((userInfo!=null)&&(userInfo.ExpirationTime>DateTime.Now))
            {
                var claims = new List<Claim>() { new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, userInfo.Name) };
                var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "myauthType");
                return new AuthenticationState(new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(identity)));
            }
            else
            {
                return new AuthenticationState(new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity()));
            }
        }
        public void Refresh()
        {
            base.NotifyAuthenticationStateChanged(GetAuthenticationStateAsync());

        }
    }

Program.cs add

//Blazored.localstroage service
builder.Services.AddBlazoredLocalStorage();

//you have to register like this, or the authenticationState won't update
builder.Services.AddScoped<MyAuthProvider>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider>(provider =>
provider.GetRequiredService<MyAuthProvider>());

//to make "authorizeview" work
builder.Services.AddCascadingAuthenticationState();

Home.razor
@page "/"
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization
@inject Blazored.LocalStorage.ILocalStorageService _localStorage
@inject MyAuthProvider _myAuthProvider
Name: <input  @bind-value ="Name" />
<br />
Password :<input @bind-value="Password"/>
<br />
<button @onclick="login">Log in</button>
<button @onclick="logout">Log out</button>
<br />
<AuthorizeView>
    <Authorized>
        You are authrized
    </Authorized>
    <NotAuthorized>
        Not authorized
    </NotAuthorized>
</AuthorizeView>

@code{
    private string Name { get; set; } = "";
    private string Password { get; set; } = "";

    private async Task login()
    {
        if ((Name == "tom")&&(Password == "123"))
        {
            await _localStorage.SetItemAsync<UserInfo>("userinfo",new UserInfo{Name="Tom",ExpirationTime=DateTime.Now.AddDays(1)});         
        }
        _myAuthProvider.Refresh();

    }
    private async Task logout()
    {
        await _localStorage.RemoveItemAsync("userinfo");
        _myAuthProvider.Refresh();
    }
}

Counter.razor
@page "/counter"
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization
@inject NavigationManager _navigationManager

<AuthorizeView>
    <Authorized>
        <h1>Counter</h1>
        <p role="status">Current count: @currentCount</p>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="IncrementCount">Click me</button>
    </Authorized>
    <NotAuthorized>
        @{
            _navigationManager.NavigateTo("/weatherforecast");
        }
    </NotAuthorized>
</AuthorizeView>

Explaination: If you are not login, visiting "Counter" will redirect you to "/weatherforecast". After login, the userinfo will be saved to localstorage. You could also do some encryption/decryption when saving values.

